# What kind of hashing is generally used in log-in modules?

Tags: hash, operating-systems, hardware

Do operating systems hash the log-in password?
What hash function is used in Windows XP, 7, 8,Linux Ubuntu, Debian, MAC Lion OS X ,...?
Where should I look to know these security considerations of an operating system?
Also is any hash function used in motherboard master password?
How about websites that require log-in passwords? Does it depend on the language which they are written with?
Does hashing prevent from all timing side-channels? I mean can you address some broken log-in modules?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to IT Security! It looks like, intentionally or no, you've embedded several questions in this one post. Due to the Q/A format of the network we would be hard pressed to adequately address them. Have a look through the [FAQ] if you need some more information. Would you mind slimming this down and possibly splitting it up into several questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What hash function is used in Windows XP, 7, 8,Linux Ubuntu, Debian, MAC Lion OS X ,...?

To answer the linux/unix (e.g., ubuntu, debian, os X) part of the question, the [crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)) hashing algorithm is typically used (but is configurable).  The standard is a salted (8 random alphanumeric character) hash that's key-strengthened about 5000 times using a simple cryptographic hash like sha256/sha512.  Again, this is configurable; e.g., see a [previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15083/is-there-repetition-in-the-solaris-11-hash-routine-can-i-add-some/15085#15085).

For various versions windows, they use LM Hash and/or NTLM hash which may be encrypted while the user is logged in.  See [wikipedia for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager); I'm not a windows user.

> Also is any hash function used in motherboard master password?

The BIOS is interesting; its so easy to reset a BIOS (remove CMOS battery without say getting the password) and difficult to otherwise read information that I've never really bothered to see how passwords are stored.  According to [this](http://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html), sometimes they are just stored in plaintext, sometimes very weakly hashed using non-cryptographic hashing functions (like CRC-16 or a flawed implementation of it).

> What about websites?

Totally depends on the configuration of the backend of the website.  Sites I set up generally use bcrypt with strength factor (base-2 log rounds) of 12.

> Does hashing prevent all timing side-channels?

No.  Constant time string comparison of the stored hash to the hash of the inputted password prevents side-channel attacks.  This is not guaranteed in all applications.  I'm confident most linuxes have this implemented correctly; and some open-site websites and web frameworks definitely do this right.  For example,  [reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/utils/utils.py) uses specifically the `constant_time_compare` used for comparing tokens as does django 1.3+, however [django 1.2 used to use a simple string equality susceptible to timing-based attacks](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14445).  Granted timing attacks are much easier to do on a local application than over a network (where a few nanosecond difference from a quick timing fail is hard to discern from random variations in network speeds).

Comment: Thanks. Can you name some weak protocols that had been broken? Perhaps a paper or a link...

Comment: @PooyaMoradi - I don't know why I said protocol when I meant `crypt algorithm` and `hashing function`.  Long week I guess.  Anyhow, not all hashing functions are intended to be difficult to reverse or generate collisions; e.g., if you are using it to generate a hashmap.  For a paper on reversing CRC-32 see: http://stigge.org/martin/pub/SAR-PR-2006-05.pdf